# Having trouble with the ternary operator while creating private route in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I'm following an online course and creating a private route component that redirects users based on an isAuthenticated state, I logged the state and it returned the else part even though the state was true.

```
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Redirect to="/login2" />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login3" />
      )
    }
  />
```

it redirects to login3 even if the state is true.

Comment: It it true immediately or is there some asynchronous stuff happening?

Comment: if have "isAuthenticated" state available from props, change your code as below
`<Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      props.isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Redirect to="/login2" />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login3" />
      )
    }
  />`

Comment: They only refer to `isAuthenticated` as being `state`, not `props`. If that indeed is the issue, please read up on the difference [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props).

Comment: @BrianThompson it's true before loading the page

Comment: Can you show where you are logging it?

Comment: @user2063635 it isn't  available from props. the props are with the render

Comment: @BrianThompson I use redux dev tool and I console.logged it before the condition

Comment: What is the exact value logged? It doesn't happen to be a string `'true'` does it?

Comment: not really, I changed the value in the reducer to true without the quotation.

Comment: Then at this point, I don't think we can help you without a little more context. Perhaps more of the code, with console logs included. A screenshot of the console showing the output might be helpful too. But at this point we can only guess, the code looks fine.

Comment: @BrianThompson I'll try to fix it and if I fail I will add more context

Answer (score 0):

From where are you getting isAuthenticated ? Is it a props or are you using redux?

If it props then write `props.isAuthenticated` it will work